# Attitude in Windows 8.1 apps

Tags: sphero-api

I want to experiment with Attitude events in C# on Windows 8.1 which I don't believe is supported just yet in the SDK.  I assume that if I dropped down to the protocol API I could get these events to flow.  Is this correct?  If so, anyone have a c# code sample of how I Could request the data stream and receive and process the data packets?

-Russ

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for the API here, it should have the information you need to request and process the attitude data from Sphero

https://github.com/orbotix/DeveloperResources